# mostrar un alert al seleccionar una opcion

Tags: php, javascript

quisiera saber como mostrar un alert en javascript cuando se seleccione una opcion de una lista.

mi codigo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<select id="test">
<option id="uno" value="uno">uno</option>
<option id="dos" value="dos">dos</option>
</select>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#test").change(function () {            
            var op = $(this).val();
            switch (op) {
                case "dos":
                alert("uno");
                    break;
                case "uno":
                alert("dos");
            }
        });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te faltaba cerrar el `$(document).ready()`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<select id="test">
<option id="uno" value="uno">uno</option>
<option id="dos" value="dos">dos</option>
</select>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#test").on('change', function () {            
            var op = $(this).val();
            switch (op) {
                case "dos":
                    alert("uno");
                    break;
                case "uno":
                    alert("dos");
                    break;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```